# How to findViewId the TextView that is done programatically

Tags: android, layout

I have a list  of textView that is programmed dynamically...

```
GridView layout = (GridView) context.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
        PrizeAdapter adapter = new PrizeAdapter(context, 0, 0, game.getPrizeList());
        layout.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Adapter Class:

```
public class PrizeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private List<String> objects;

    public PrizeAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
            List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView text = new TextView(getContext());
        text.setId(position);
        text.setText(objects.get(position));
        text.setTextSize(12);
        text.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);
        text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        text.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);
        return text;
    }

}
```

Supposedly, I have created a 10 TextView. How can i get the particular textView so i can color it differently.

I tried this

```
GridView layout = (GridView) context.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
TextView view = (TextView) layout.findViewById(1);
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
view.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

But it doesn't work and just encountered a nullpointer exception.
Please help.

Comment: view Object is null,as view is not initialised.make sure you are getting proper xml view id.

Comment: i've created the object programatically... now i don't know how to retrieve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for such behavior is you are doing it too early. 
i.e even before the view are created with id 1 you are trying to access them.

So what is happening is, you ask adapter to inflate view and adapter takes control checking what is visible and what should be displayed.
and immediately after if ( before view are populated) you call findviewbyID(1) so this view is still not created hence you get null pointer.

The code will work if we try to use a button to do the task after grid is populated.

```
  final GridView layout = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
    PrizeAdapter adapter = new PrizeAdapter(this, 0, 0, objects2);
    layout.setAdapter(adapter);


    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            TextView view = (TextView) layout.findViewById(1);
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            view.setTextColor(Color.RED);

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

So 2 solution

1) delayed handler post for changing color.

2) create a custom callback interface which will give you back result like view 1 loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ViewGroup.getChildAt(position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt%28int%29), which will return you the view at that position. Then Typecast it to TextView(as you are setting the TextView as direct item View) to set color.

One more thing you cannot use findViewById() when you are creating objects dynamically unless you set ID for the object.

Comment: i've changed it to TextView view = (TextView) layout.getChildAt(game.getPlayer().getPlayerLvl()); where layout is the GridView... but i still have the null pointer exception

Comment: what will getPlayerLvl() will return; will it be an index less than gridview items length?

Comment: even if i getChildCount(), it is always equal to 0